# How to check the auto alignment of text when Text contains Arabic words

Tags: qt, qml, arabic-support

I have created a Rectangle item with Text item in center which acts as Edit box with Cursor item at the end of the text.

[image: SAMPLE iMAGE]

So for Orientation to be taken care by QML, I have modified the Text item as

```
Text
    {
        id: text_input
        font.bold: true
        font.pixelSize: 22
        color: "white"
        text:  view.defaultTextField
        elide: Text.ElideLeft
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        anchors.fill: parent
        maximumLineCount: 1

        clip: true

        anchors{
            rightMargin: 10
            leftMargin: (textInputField === "") ? 18 : 12
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }
```

and Cursor image as

```
Image
    {
        id: img_cursor

        x: (textInputField !== "") ?
              (text_input.x + text_input.contentWidth)) : 12

        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        source: "text_cursor.png"
    }
```

Now if textInputField contains Arabic text, TextItem is auto change the orientation from right to left. and english it is changing to start from Left.
Text appending coming in :
Arabic: Left <--Right
English: Left --> Right

But for Cursor position, how i can make the logic to auto detect and change the x position of the cursor based on the text_input orientation direction (Arabic and English).

Comment: Do you have any method of how to detect if the text is Arabic or English?

Comment: @eyllanesc: yes I tried using RegEx to detect arabic language . But the problem is , Characters can mix. If we starts with numeric and arab, it still change orientation from Right to left. Only if it starts with english character and arab , it stays in left to right orientation. so RegEx detection is failing in some scenarios.

Comment: @Wagmare ever thought about using TextInput component?
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#acceptableInput-prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arabic isn't *always* RtoL. Numbers, for example, are written LtoR (just like in English). Also, foreign words would be written LtoR. Conversely, if you add an Arabic word in an English text, text direction will change somewhere. Might be the middle of the line, might be at either end.

That's why a simple trick like calling QFontMetrics.width() will only work for simple cases.

Try [QTextLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextlayout.html) instead. QLineEdit uses this code in it's control to figure out the X position of the cursor:

```
qreal cursorToX(int cursor) const { return m_textLayout.lineAt(0).cursorToX(cursor); }
```

Comment: Is there any implementation similar in QML. based on my implementation.

Comment: @Wagmare I think this is outside of what QML can do. I'd write a small widget and then register that with QML: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html

Comment: I have updated the answer below on fixing the issue with QML. but thanks a lot for the example and suggestion.

Comment: @Wagmare Does that work when mix numbers and Arabic words?

Comment: Yes without failing. tested completely

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to check the alignment of the text. so on arabic change , the Text orientation will be modified automatically.

```
function isArabicAlignment() {

        if(text_input.horizontalAlignment === Text.AlignRight)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

So on Text input modifies , i will check the condition and update the cursor position.

```
x: (textInputField !== "" && isArabicAlignment()) ?
              (text_input.x + text_input.contentWidth)) : //Changing Cursor in reverse.
```